# Nodejs subfolder script

Tags: node.js, subdirectory

I'm trying to use one script on port 81 to manage multiple other express script.

I'm trying to do this :

server.com => Main server on port 81

- First express on port 8881 => accessible on server.com/first
- Second express on port 8882 => accessible on server.com/second
- ...

I've try with vhost (express/connect vhost) but i don't want to use multiple subdomain.

If someone know how i can do this...or where is my mistake...
Thank's!

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Can you show us some code or edit your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to proxy requests to different ports you could look into [Bouncy](https://github.com/substack/bouncy).

Another option (if the two apps are related, for instance two sections of the same website) is to use the two Express apps as sub-apps of a main Express application. To do this you would create one main Express app running on port 81, and include the lines:

```
var first  = require('path/to/first');
var second = require('path/to/second');

app.use('/first', first);
app.use('/second', second);
```

This will effectively 'mount' your apps into the larger application at the given mount location. I would probably only do this is the apps are related in some way.